# Spot simulation in Webots becomes unstable after lifting one leg

Tags: webots, stability

I have written a custom controller for the Spot robot that comes in-built with Webots. based on the already given controller. I am having an issue where when I try to lift one leg off from the ground, the entire robot becomes unstable, the projection of the COM quickly leaves the boundaries of the support polygon, this shoudln't happen.

I tried different ways of lifting the leg just to factor out accidentally pushing the robot, but it still falls over.

Does anyone have any idea why is it doing this? Could it be a problem with the model itself?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.